# Extending the directive to not show two decimal places

Tags: javascript, angular

i have written a directive that accepts numbers and depending on whether for e.g it is  10,000 or 10,000,000 it would return 10k, 10M etc. One screen in my website needs the value to be displayed in 2 decimal places while the other screen doesn't. My current implementation shows the number upto 2 decimal places. How do i extend it to not show when required

```
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'shortNumberFormat'
})
export class ShortNumberFormatDirective implements PipeTransform {

  constructor() { }

   transform(number: any) {

    if (number == null || isNaN(number)) {
      return;
    }

    const hasMinus = String(number).charAt(0) === '-' ? true : false;
    number =  String(number).charAt(0) === '-' ?
            + String(number).substring(1, number.length)  : number;

        if (number <= 999) { // hundreds
          number = number.toFixed(2) ;
        } else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 999999) {  // thousands
          number = (number / 1000).toFixed(2) + 'K';
        } else if (number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999) { // millions
          number = (number / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 'M';
        } else if (number >= 1000000000 && number <= 999999999999) { // billions
          number = (number / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + 'B';
        }
        if (hasMinus) {
          return '-' + number;
        } else {
          return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Nicky, I didnt get what has the link that you shared got to do with my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes):

> The pipe class implements the PipeTransform interface's transform
>   method that accepts an input value followed by **optional parameters** and
>   returns the transformed value.

This allows you to set a default of zero decimals for most cases, but optionally pass in a `2` to get two decimal places.

```
import {Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'shortNumberFormat'
})
export class ShortNumberFormatDirective implements PipeTransform {

  transform(number: any, decimals = 0) {

    if (number == null) {
      return;
    }

    number = parseFloat(number);

    if (isNaN(number)) {
      return;
    }

    const signPrefix = number < 0 ? '-' : '';
    number = Math.abs(number);

    if (number <= 999) { // hundreds
      number = number.toFixed(decimals);
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 999999) {  // thousands
      number = (number / 1000).toFixed(decimals) + 'K';
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999) { // millions
      number = (number / 1000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'M';
    } else { // billions
      number = (number / 1000000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'B';
    }

    return signPrefix + number;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error I am getting the following error toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 100

Comment: I am calling it like this {{item.minSize| shortNumberFormat: item.minSize }}

Comment: I think there is somethingwrong in the way i am calling. While i debug , I can see value for eg 20,000 being passed to both the parameters.

Comment: If i try this {{item.minSize| shortNumberFormat: 'item.minSize'}} it works but if i try this {{item.minSize| shortNumberFormat: 'item.minSize':'2'}} it doesnt. Get the same error toFixed() digits argument must be between 0 and 100
    at Number.toFixed

Comment: what is the value of `decimals` when you call it that way?

Comment: It very strange. I can see in the value of item.minsize being set for both the parameters. It doesnt seem to take the value 0 or 2 passed to the pipe

Comment: I would expect item.minsize to be passed for both is you're using 
`{{item.minSize| shortNumberFormat: item.minSize }}`. 
Try `{{item.minSize | shortNumberFormat: 2 }}`

Comment: Yes. The issue has been resolved. What i was passing earlier was incorrect. It worked by passing it {{item.minSize| shortNumberFormat: 2}}

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter boolean **isRequired** to your Pipe, to tell whether or not you need to apply the pipe.

```
 transform(number: any, isRequired: boolean) {

    if (number == null || isNaN(number)) {
      return;
    }
    if (isRequired) return number;
    else {

    const hasMinus = String(number).charAt(0) === '-' ? true : false;
    number =  String(number).charAt(0) === '-' ?
            + String(number).substring(1, number.length)  : number;

        if (number <= 999) { // hundreds
          number = number.toFixed(2) ;
        } else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 999999) {  // thousands
          number = (number / 1000).toFixed(2) + 'K';
        } else if (number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999) { // millions
          number = (number / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 'M';
        } else if (number >= 1000000000 && number <= 999999999999) { // billions
          number = (number / 1000000000).toFixed(2) + 'B';
        }
        if (hasMinus) {
          return '-' + number;
        } else {
          return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add a paramter when you want the pipe to not change the format like this:  `{{ 1000000 | shortNumberFormat:true }}`

Comment: I think you didnt get  my question or I am not very clear. In both instances i need to show the pipe. The only difference is that in one instance it will show with 2 decimal places and in other instance it wont

Comment: "The only difference is that in one instance it will show with 2 decimal places and in other instance it wont" Based on what? What do you mean mean by "it won't"? Can you give us a concrete example on what you want ? Do you want the the display result to depend on the screen size? It's honestly unclear what you want to achieve!